# Android Studio: "Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown"

Tags: java, android, gradle

Getting Error:
"Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown"
while trying to sync an android folder of a react-native repo in android studio.

Java:
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)

Android Gradle Plugin Version - 4.1.3
Gradle Version - 6.9

I didn't get any specific error description. I have tried by changing the Gradle version and java version, android studio reinstall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm just getting that error with no details. All I can do is provide the full log file.